# How to rename deb package?

Tags: package-management

I get package source by typing:
`sudo apt-get source nginx`

and added `--add-module=/usr/src/nginx-rtmp-module \` string to `debian/rules`

How I can rename packages from `nginx-*` to `nginx-rtmp-*`?

Answer (score 1):

You would change the name in the control file (debain/control), on the Package line.

See https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html and https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Package

Answer (score 0):

I would not rename the nginx-* binary packages, as you'll also have to rename all their dependencies in debian/control and moreover it will overwrite standard nginx files if you install the packages you built from source (e.g the nginx service file).

Instead I'd install the one you built without trying to rename them. You'll be able to use the Ubuntu version later using a package manager like synaptic or the apt command line tools.

To build the nginx packages from source with the nginx-rtmp-module, use the following procedure:

```
cd /tmp && apt-get source nginx
git clone https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module.git
```

Edit your `/tmp/nginx-1.4.1/debian/rules` to add `--add-module=/usr/src/nginx-rtmp-module \` under `config.status.full`

```
cd nginx-1.4.1/
sudo apt-get install libgd2-dev libgeoip-dev liblua5.1-dev libmhash-dev libpam0g-dev libperl-dev
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -b
```

This will create many different debian packages. Grab the ones for the flavor you need and install!

To determine if your module got compiled/installed correctly use 'nginx -V' to see the compiled in modules. Your module should be in this list.

Comment: I want to use obtained packages in my repository to simply deploy them on servers with puppet manifests. And different name allow me simply add my repo to `source.list` without priority setting.

Comment: By priority did you mean pinning and /etc/apt/preferences use? Again I would avoid renaming and use pinning for the nginx* packages. If the sources or packaging change, the update path will be less painful